# make jquery selector return a result when url matches

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

## I need to write a jquery selector that returns something in the DOM, if the url of the site matches a predetermined url.

As background I'm writing a documentation feature that was designed for "single" sites, however I need to use it for a documentation over multiple sites. I do not have control over the Server or the Code. Neither can I choose another framework.

 I know that jquery selectors where not designed for this so I'm looking for anything that just works

I'm looking for a selector with the following behaviour

say im on http://someurl/correctpage 
 then the selecor should return something from the DOM via $('SELECTORHERE')

 however if im on http://someurl/falsepage it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [hash](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

```js
$(function() {
  // we get hash value 
  let hashValue = location.hash;

  hashValue = "correctpage"; // this line is for test only

  // we check if the hash value is egal to your second tab name
  if (hashValue == "correctpage") { 
    $("." + hashValue).removeClass("red").addClass("green");
  }
});
```

```css
.red { border: 1px solid red }
.green { border: 1px solid green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="correctpage red">Test</div>
```

Comment: thanks for taking a run at it, however I am not able to use javascript at all. I can only supply a selector that will be used in an expression like this $('MYWONDERFULLSELECTOR') and will be able to see wether that expression found an element in the page